# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - second POST returns 400

Tags: post, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. I am able to login and click around (`GET` requests) without any issue.

When I post a form to update an object, it works the first time. The app returns the same view with a success message.

If I click submit again and again it works but if I change a value on the form and hit submit it fails with a 400 error, but it never gets to my controller.

I need help to understand what is intervening so I can make the form post successfully and hit the controller action.

If it helps, here is the Program.cs file for it:

```
using Common;
using Common.Utils;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy;
using ProcessBlockMvcClient;
using System.Net;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddCors();
Initialisation.AddServices(builder.Services);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

//Add config from config file
var appSettingsSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection(Constants.APP_SETTINGS);
builder.Services.Configure<ClientAppSettingsModel>(appSettingsSection);

//setup the app
var app = builder.Build();
var logWrapper = app.Services.GetService<ILogWrapper>();
logWrapper.InfoFormat($"Web Server starting...");
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
};
app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

/*
 * Need the below to redirect to login page upon 401 or 403 
 * Order of these App.XYZ is important
 * Need UseAuthentication, followed by Routing and Status Code Pages and lastly UseAuthorization()
 */
app.UseStatusCodePages(context => {
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
        response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        response.Redirect("/User/Login");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Only provide `Program.cs` can't solve anthing. Will the form fail to submit if you make any changes? `400 error` is a client-side error, you can check the value on the form whtich you changed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. I had two threads one reading the cookie and decoding it from the request and setting it on the response and another thread was just updating the cookie. Both threads, however, was calling `await httpContext.SignInAsync(...)` and I don't think ASP .NET likes you calling SignIn multiple times concurrently.

I have since removed the threading, kept the code to just updating the cookie and removed the calls to `SignInAsync` - those are left for when the user logs in only.